# new objects don't replace with deleted objects in Postgres

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I'm new on Django and I use PostgreSQL with it. I added some objects to server and deleted them and now understood that id of new objects don't  replace with deleted objects and they continue.
for example when I deleted 4th object, next new objects is 5.

I get objects IDs by:

```
path('<int:blog_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

in urls.py

then I try to get the related object by:

```
def detail(request, blog_id):
    detailblog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', {'blog': detailblog})
```

in views.py

it works for objects that now are in DB.
but for deleted objects for example 4th object here is the error:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/4/ Raised by:    blog.views.detail No
>   Blog matches the given query.

Comment: Yes. So what's your question? Why is this a problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What you're describing seems to reflect both what you will happen, and how Django works. Can you clarify what's your question?

Comment: I appreciate you for formatting my question.
let me say that in another way: now I have 3 objects in my Blog but their blog_id is 11, 12 & 13. I want them to be 1, 2 , 3

Comment: You should not. If this is important for you on dev/test stage - read how to update/reset ID in PG docs. If you want it to happen on prod, when users insert/edit/delete something - don't. After applying sort order they will be _the first_, _the second_ and so on, no need to play with IDs. Also different posts are supposed to have different content in this case substituting one post contents with another's is a little bit criminal. So just forget it or rephrase your question - describe what you need this for.

Comment: Actually it wasn't so necessary, I was just challenging myself and I thought it is usual to sort objects in this way